# Spring Boot static resources served from context path issue

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I have a Angular UI which i deployed as a Spring Boot Web WAR file on a Jboss container (By moving all html, js, css files to /resources/static folder). I used mvn package to create the WAR file and deployed it on Jboss. Now i realized that all static resources like my app.js are loaded in http://localhost/appcontext/js/app.js. 
In my angular code i just have

```
   <body>
     <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js">     </script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cdaguerre/gmaps- utility-library/4f71018696f179acabbe445f188fc2de13f60c3e/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
   </body>
```

When the code is executed, it is trying to look for app.js in  http://localhost/js/app.js and doesnt find it. How do i make all static resources to load from http://localhost/appcontext?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call the resources specifiying their location relative to where they are?
Something like `<script src="appcontext/js/app.js"></script>`.

It seems that's what you need, but maybe I'm missunderstanding your problem

Comment: The container moves the resources to another URL. So if this is changed to appcontext/ it won't work when running Angular locally.

Comment: Another problem with this solution is that the `<script src="...">` tag isn't something you program, it is being auto generated by angular inside the index.html file. So you can't really seem to control the contents, it uses defaults?